# error: No match to call the 'module'

Tags: c++, object, module, systemc

I am not able to initialize or call `full_adder` module for combining multiple `full_adder`.

```
Getting error 
error: no match for call to ‘(full_adder) (sc_core::sc_signal_in_if<sc_dt::sc_uint<4> >*, sc_core::sc_signal_in_if<sc_dt::sc_uint<4> >*, sc_core::sc_signal<bool, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0u>&, sc_core::sc_signal_inout_if<sc_dt::sc_uint<4> >*, sc_core::sc_signal<bool, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0u>&)’
  (*fa0_ptr) (a[0],b[0], c0,sum[0],c0);
```

help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my sample code.

**full_adder.h**

```
SC_MODULE(full_adder)
{
        sc_in<bool> a,b, carry_in;
        sc_out<bool> sum, carry_out;

        sc_signal<bool> c1,s1,c2;
        void prc_or();
contd.......
```

**fourbit_adder.h**

```
#include "full_adder.h"

SC_MODULE(fourbit_adder)
{
        sc_in<sc_uint<4> > a,b;
        sc_in<bool> carry_in;
        sc_out<sc_uint<4> > sum;
        sc_out<bool> carry_out;



        sc_signal<bool> c0,c1,c2;
        void prc_or();
        full_adder *fa0_ptr, *fa1_ptr, *fa2_ptr, *fa3_ptr;

        SC_CTOR(fourbit_adder)
        {

        fa0_ptr = new full_adder("fa0"); // constructor operator which allocates and initialize the memory.
        //Positional association
        (*fa0_ptr) (a[0],b[0], c0,sum[0],c0);
```

Comment: You need to post some code for help. Just the error message is not very useful by itself.

Comment: is `Getting error` part of the output or did you put it there?

Comment: @Neuron part of the output.

Comment: compilation unsucessful

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, yes you can cast `int` to `bool` but that is not really your issue. You are trying to connect signals and ports (or interfaces and channels) together. And although the channels carry `int` and `bool`, the channels themselves are of totally different types (for example `sc_in<bool>` and `sc_signal< sc_int<99> >` are of incompatible types).

The simplest solution is to just use an intermediate module to convert the signals. That is, one that takes an `sc_int<W>` and converts it to an array of W boolean signals (or vice versa). What I think you may be looking for is the `sc_int_bitref` class that can reference a bit with an `sc_int` or `sc_uint`.

Here is a quick but fully working example. The template class `UintToBits` module has one signal of type `sc_uint` and an array of `bool` signals. The module process is sensitive to the `sc_uint` signal and updates all the `bool` signals when triggered. You could take this to the n'th degree with template template classes (`sc_int/sc_uint/sc_lv` etc) but this is just a simple solution that should get you working.

template 
SC_MODULE(UintToBits){

```
typedef sc_uint<W>  UintType;   //type of sc_uint
sc_signal<UintType> uint_i;     //input signal sc_uint
sc_signal<bool>     bool_o[W];  //output signal W x bool

SC_CTOR(UintToBits){
    SC_METHOD(proc);        //setup conversion proc
    sensitive << uint_i;    //and kick it off when uint changes
}

void proc(){
    UintType value = uint_i;    //get the uint value
    for(int i = 0; i < W; ++i){ //for each bit in uint
        bool_o[i] = value[i];   //bool o/p sc_int_bitref[i]
    }
}
```

};

To demonstrate assume we have the class below that takes a single bit input.

//Some random module take takes a single bit input
SC_MODULE(ModuleBit){

```
sc_in_clk clk_i;        //just to make it go
sc_in<bool> bool_i;     //bit input

SC_CTOR(ModuleBit){
    SC_METHOD(proc);    //a proc just to print out the bit
    sensitive << clk_i.pos();
    dont_initialize();
}

void proc(){ cout << bool_i; }
```

};

And this block that outputs an `sc_uint`

//Some random module with data of sc_uint
SC_MODULE(ModuleBitsW){

```
sc_in_clk clk_i;            //just to make it go
sc_out<UintType> uint_o;    //the sc_uint

SC_CTOR(ModuleBitsW){
    SC_METHOD(proc);        //proc just to change the output
    sensitive << clk_i.pos();
    uint_o.initialize(0);
    dont_initialize();
}

void proc(){
    uint_o = uint_o->read() + 1;    //output current value + 1
    cout << '\n'; //emit nl to make seperate bool modules o/ps
}
```

};

Then we can connect them together using the intermediary converter module.

int sc_main(int, char**){

```
const int W = 4; //Assume we have 4 bits
typedef UintToBits<W>::UintType UintType;


sc_clock clock("clock", 1.0, SC_SEC);   //randomly chosen one second period clock 

//create the sc_uint module, the bool modules and the converter module
UintToBits<W> convert("convert");   //converts sc_uint signal to W x bool signals
ModuleBitsW bitsw_m("bitsw_m");     //module with sc_uint output
ModuleBit* bit_m[W];                //W x modules needing single bit input

//connect the single bit modules
for(int i = 0; i < W; ++i){
    bit_m[i] = new ModuleBit(("m" + to_string(i)).c_str());
    bit_m[i]->bool_i(convert.bool_o[W-i-1]);    //reverse them to print 'normally' (not guaranteed)
    bit_m[i]->clk_i(clock);
}
bitsw_m.uint_o(convert.uint_i); //connect output of sc_uint module to converter module
bitsw_m.clk_i(clock);           //just to drive it


sc_start(20.0, SC_SEC);     //run it for 20 cycles and see what we get
return 0;
```

//let process clear up memory am too lazy
}

Which when I ran it gave the output
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
0000
0001
0010
0011

I used these includes `<systemc>, <iostream>` and imported these namespaces `sc_core, sc_dt, std` and compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 FullAdder.cpp -lsystemc` with gcc 4.9.2` on linux64

This should get you past your problem for now but if you expect to be doing a lot of serial-parallel conversions it might be worth your while designing a small set of templates (or more likely template-template classes). And finally don't forget the very useful `sc_int_bitref` returned from `sc_int[]` operator but you'll need a signal (not just a `bool` or `int`) to get change notifications to drive processes.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `sum[0]` as the 4th argument in `(*fa0_ptr) (a[0],b[0], c0,sum[0],c0)` which is of type `sc_uint` but the 4th member of `full_adder` is of type `bool`.

Comment: is there any way i can typecast to convert from int to bool

Comment: do i need to change uint to bool of sum

Comment: I'm not seeing a way of converting sc_uint to individual bits. [This post](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/1629-how-to-link-bool-port-with-sc-int/) actually looks very similar to what you're trying to do and the consensus seems to be you can't do it with sc_uint. They suggest looking at somethjing called sc_vector instead.

Comment: You might be able to get it to work by changing some of those `bool` in the `full_adder` to `sc_uint<1>`. From my reading it looks like `sc_uint<1>` is the type returned by the index operator on an `sc_uint<4>`.